# How can I add a parameter to a list in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, parameters

How can I add a parameter to this list  ?

```
putIntoList :: a -> [a] 
putIntoList = ?
```

Comment: Exactly what do you try to achieve here. It is not really clear to me what you mean with "how can I add a parameter"? Please *rewrite* you question, add sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to *what* list? Your type only specifies one parameter, and a list result. You thus do not add to a list, but rather *create* a new list from a given value:

```
putIntoList :: a -> [a]     -- type
putIntoList = \a -> [a]     -- value
```

is the only thing it can do. Or actually,

```
putIntoList :: a -> [a]        -- type
putIntoList = \a -> [a,a,a]    -- value
```

is another possibility. Or *any* number of repetitions of the same value, which we got as a parameter to this function.

There's thus one more possibility (besides returning an error):

```
putIntoList :: a -> [a] 
putIntoList = \a -> [ ....
```

Do finish this definition.